# Add powerpoint template preview in html

Tags: html, web, powerpoint

I'm sorry I'm new to this. I have been looking for a solution for this, but I can't find any.I want to add into my web page the preview of the powerpoint templates.

These powerpoint templates are uploaded and after the upload, it is supposed to display its preview in the web.

Thank you!

Comment: Why not export a JPG or other image from a presentation based on your template and use that as the preview?

Comment: Would that be possible if after uploading a presentation template, it will generate automatically a jpg image?

Comment: In theory, sure.  In practice, Microsoft recommends against automating PowerPoint on the server. A client-side add-in that creates the JPG and handles the upload to the server might be a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to add them to your google docs and then use:

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://www.yourwebsite.com/powerpoint.ppt&embedded=true" style="width:600px; height:500px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```